# copy array and add 1 to its size using printall() method to return all int in new array

Tags: java, arrays

This is a homework assignment that I have not been able to complete. I am close, but I am having trouble understanding how to finish. Any help is greatly appreciated.

- Implement a class Arrayplus1() that takes an integer array data and an int x as its size. Create a method inside the class Arrayplus1()
  that creates a new array whose length is one greater than data’s length.
- Then create a method to copy all data’s elements into the new array and add the value of x into the last element of the array.
- Create a printall()  method to return all the integers in the new array.
- I am not sure what to do with the size = i part.

Code:

```
package addarray19;

class Arrayplus1{
  int[]array ={1,2,3,4,5};
  int[]newarray = array;
  int size;
  int data; 

  public Arrayplus1(int i){
    size = i;
  }

  class Arrayadd{
    int[]newarray = new int[array.length +1 ];
  }

  void printall(){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      newarray[i] = array[i];    
    }
    array = newarray;     
  }
  void copy(){
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newarray, 0, array.length);
    newarray[5] = 5;
  }

}

public class Addarray19{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Addarray19 array = new Addarray19(); 
    array.printall();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your requirements correctly, you're supposed to append the `int x` to your `data` array. Based on that assumption, the instruction to write a routine to first "grow" the data array might be implemented readily enough. First, set a default to `1` (because adding anything to an empty array should be a one element array). Next, check that the `data` isn't null. If it isn't take its' length and add one as the `size`. Then `return` a new `int[]` of length `size` like

```
static int[] growArray(int[] data) {
    int size = 1;
    if (data != null) {
        size = 1 + data.length;
    }
    return new int[size];
}
```

Next, your method to `add` to the array is to first grow it then copy the values and finally append the new element at the end. Like,

```
private static int[] addToArray(int[] data, int x) {
    int[] array2 = growArray(data);
    if (data != null) {
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, array2, 0, data.length);
    }
    array2[array2.length - 1] = x;
    return array2;
}
```

Then, you can implement your required `Arrayplus1` constructor like

```
private int[] data;
public Arrayplus1(int[] data, int x) {
    this.data = addToArray(data, x);
}
```

Next, `printall` should do something like

```
public void printall() {
    System.out.print(data[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(", %d", data[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Finally, your `main()` method should be instantiating `Arrayplus1` instances... For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] in = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int x = 4;
    Arrayplus1 a = new Arrayplus1(null, 1);
    a.printall();
    Arrayplus1 b = new Arrayplus1(in, x);
    b.printall();
}
```

and the output is

```
1
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overlooking the first requirement. The constructor should take BOTH an integer array AND an int for size. The int for size in the class should represent and remember the length of data stored in int[] array

```
class Arrayplus1{
  int[] array;
  int size;
  public Arrayplus1(int[] a, int i){
    array = a;
    size = i; 

  }
}
```